Finding close approximately of 3D points by converting to Color spaces
Consider I have an array of points in 3D with known XYZ. And want to find the points that are close to each other. for example, finding points whose Euclidean distance is less than the delta. this procedure will take O(n^2) time. If I consider these XYZ as Red Green Blue (of course consider these points are from 0 to 255). Is there a color space that could lower the dimension of the problem to find similar colors by converting RGB to that color space and checking the color similarity as a form of the original problem? this way if there is a color space that could use one of its channels as color similarity I Could sort the dimension in O(nlogn) time and find the similarity. of course, this idea is realistic when the conversion algorithm takes less than O(n^2) time.

how many vertices/colors do you have to deal with? -- this is a typical computer graphics task. nearest neighbor query. oct-trees or BSP or other data structures and algorithms on them.

no, there is no color space with less than three dimensions that still captures the original data. if you drop a dimension, you drop some information. you can do that, but you'd have to decide what aspect of your colors you don't care about. why would you even want to? use the right algorithms and data structures and you won't have to face the O(n^2) complexity.

Thanks, @ChristophRackwitz for your comment. I was just wondering if I could see the problem from a new angle and check if there could be other approaches.
